# Are gtag events elaborated in real time?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

A simple question: are Google Analytics 4 events, like `gtag('event', 'purchase', ...)`, elaborated and shown on the dashboard immediately or is there a delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation from Google Analytics, there is a delay in processing events. The delay is typically between 20 minutes and 24-48 hours [Data Freshness](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11198161?hl=en). However, events that arrive up to 72 hours late are still processed in Google Analytics 4 [UA vs GA4](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9964640?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article).

Data Freshness is how long it takes Google Analytics to collect and process an event from your property. If that process takes 20 minutes, then data freshness is 20 minutes.